# Which NFC Tag is this? nfc-list Mifare Ultralight/Classic 7Byte UID

Tags: nfc, mifare, lib-nfc

Which NFC Tag is this?

ATQA 00 44 SAK 00 = Mifare Ultralight 7Byte UID

ATQA 00 04 SAK 08 = Mifare Classic 1K 4Byte UID

Mine: ATQA 00 44 SAK 08 16 Sectors 64 Blocks

```
$ nfc-list
nfc-list uses libnfc libnfc-1.7.1-191-g216145f
NFC device: ACS ACR122U / ACR122U214 opened
1 ISO14443A passive target(s) found:
ISO/IEC 14443A (106 kbps) target:
ATQA (SENS_RES): 00 44
UID (NFCID1): 02 d7 f9 c2 a4 29 10
SAK (SEL_RES): 08
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be Mifare Classic 1K with a double-size (7 byte) UID

Comment: Do you know where I can get those cards with a writable block 0 and UID? I want to clone a card

Comment: Not really... UID should not be writable. I've heard such cards exist but I have never had one in my hands.